# How to number the rows of incoming data from SerialPort?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am Reading data from serialport and saving in a textfile. 
After saving in a textfile, my data looks like:

```
    150101 05:01:29,4 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;80;10;E008
    150101 05:01:29,5 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;80;10;E008
    150101 05:01:29,6 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;00;10;E008
```

I want to number the rows in the saved textfile, Like this:

```
    150101 05:01:29,4 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;80;10;E008;1 
    150101 05:01:29,5 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;80;10;E008;2
    150101 05:01:29,6 0030;0000;00;00;00;00;0000;0000;00;10;E008,3
```

My code looks like:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

         RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
          AppendToFile(RxString);
    }
    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     textBox1.AppendText(RxString + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void AppendToFile(string toAppend)
    {

         string myFilePath = @"C: \Users\Glenn\Desktop\data1.txt";
         File.AppendAllText(myFilePath, toAppend + Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: just add your number while adding the data to the text file

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: U can add at **AppendToFile(RxString+i);** . Like this. As it is sending single line ata time

Comment: @user3306920 It works but the line number remains the same in every row. Every row has a row number of 1.

Comment: Increment the 'i' value in any method..

Comment: Or create any text/ini file. Read and update the number of the current line.
Make the number to 1 after completing or before starting the process.

Comment: Get the Text file lines count and update the next line number.

Use this to get the No. of lines from text file 
'int lines = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\abc123.txt").Length;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a proper looking class out of that bit you posted, plus what you need to add to it to get your line numbering:

```
public class SerialPortReader
{
    private const _filePath = @"C:\Users\Glenn\Desktop\data1.txt";
    private Int32 _lineNumber = 1;

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
        AppendToFile(RxString);
    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(RxString + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void AppendToFile(string toAppend)
    {
        var line = String.Format("{0};{1}\n", toAppend, _lineNumber);
        File.AppendAllText(_filePath, line);
        _lineNumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but the line number remains the same in every row. Every row have a row number of 1. The _lineNumber++ dont work?

Comment: That would suggest you are instantiating the `SerialPortReader` class each time.  If you had a single instance that was reused, this would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a class-level row counter:

```
private int _currentRowNum = 1;
```

Then you would do this in your `AppendToFile` method:

```
File.AppendAllLines(myFilePath, new string[] {string.Format("{0};{1}", toAppend, _currentRowNum.ToString())});
_currentRowNum++;
```

Comment: It gives me error says " Arument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string' .

Answer (score 0):

This may be simple.Here I get all lines; add numbers at the end and write to a new file.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("../../Data/test.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

List<string> list = new List<string>();
int lineCount=1;
foreach(string line in lines)
{
     list.Add(line + ";" + lineCount++);
}
File.WriteAllLines("../../Data/test.txt", list.ToArray());
```

Comment: Is it possible to number the rows in the same file? without creating a second file. Thanks

Comment: no issues... modified the code for you